# AWS Elemental MediaConvert Video File trimming start and end duration

Tags: javascript, file, aws-media-convert

Just wanted to know How I handle a video trimming from AWS Elemental MediaConvert when the user upload's a video file through JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MediaConvert requires you to set the SDK to use a specific API input [1,2]

The JavaScript SDK docs [3] call out how to define and create a job in MeidaConvert using the JS SDK. In order to accomplish input clipping you would need to add the `InputClippings` option to your `Input` JSON block. An example is below:

```
"Inputs": [
      {
        "AudioSelectors": {
          "Audio Selector 1": {
            "Offset": 0,
            "DefaultSelection": "NOT_DEFAULT",
            "ProgramSelection": 1,
            "SelectorType": "TRACK",
            "Tracks": [
              1
            ]
          }
        },
        "VideoSelector": {
          "ColorSpace": "FOLLOW"
        },
        "FilterEnable": "AUTO",
        "PsiControl": "USE_PSI",
        "FilterStrength": 0,
        "DeblockFilter": "DISABLED",
        "DenoiseFilter": "DISABLED",
        "TimecodeSource": "ZEROBASED",
        "FileInput": "s3://INPUT_BUCKET_AND_FILE_NAME",
        "InputClippings": [
          {
            "StartTimecode": "00:00:00:00",
            "EndTimecode": "00:05:00:00"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Keep in mind that `TimecodeSource` will affect clipping regions. If you know the source file your user is uploading contains embedded timecode, you can change this to `EMBEDDED`, for more information see the documentation [4]

== Resources == 
[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/emc-examples-jobs.html#emc-examples-jobs-configure-sdk 
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/apireference/custom-endpoints.html 
[3]https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/emc-examples-jobs.html#emc-examples-jobs-spec 
[4] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/setting-up-an-assembly-workflow-job.html

Comment: jjohn can u please look into link shared below and let me know suggestions
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67402231/aws-elemental-mediaconvert-createjob-example-using-the-aws-sdk-for-net